# SQL Server add file cause 317 error code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I created file group with filestream. Now I want to add file:

```
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.filegroups where name = 'FileStreamGroup') 
            BEGIN
                ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
                ADD FILE
                (
                    NAME = 'file_blobs',
                    FILENAME= 'F:\SqlExprInstance\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\file_blobs'
                )
                TO FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup
            END
```

But I get this strange error:

> Unable to open the physical file
>   "F:\SqlExprInstance\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\file_blobs".
>   Operating system error -1071906801: "0xc01c000f(failed to retrieve
>   text for this error. Reason: 317)".

What can cause this error?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  The SQL Server job doesn't have access to the file or the file doesn't exist.

Comment: If I manualy create it, it will give me error that this file **already** exist, and I gave full permissions to SQL instance on this DATA folder in Security settings of the directory. So, no, it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation when location of the files was not default one. I seems that adding permissions via Explorer is not enough. Try to do following from command prompt:

```
--Go to DATA folder
ICACLS *.* /grant [MsSqlServerAccount]:F.
```