# SQLEXPRESS Server 2014 yet another FILESTREAM bug?

Tags: sql-server

When I try to go along tutorial of using this:

```
        EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
        RECONFIGURE
        GO

        CREATE DATABASE Archive 
        ON
        PRIMARY(NAME = Arch1,
                FILENAME = 'c:\data\archdat1.mdf'),
        FILEGROUP FileStreamGroup1 CONTAINS FILESTREAM(NAME = Arch3,
        FILENAME = 'c:\data\filestream1')
        LOG ON(NAME = Archlog1,
        FILENAME = 'c:\data\archlog1.ldf')
        GO
```

I get following error in events:

> Operating system error 0xc01c000f(failed to retrieve text for this
>   error. Reason: 317) occurred while creating or opening file
>   'c:\data\filestream1'.

Well, I tried to find solution and actually found quite a lot of them:

- Try change service account to **Log On As** *username*
- Try change service account to **Local System**
- Try adding everyone in the world to c:\data folder access rights

So far no success, and it looks to me like regression from Microsoft. What am I doing wrong?

All FileStream features enabled in SQL Configuration Manager.
*Windows 10 SQL 2014 Express*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server add file cause 317 error code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44241776/sql-server-add-file-cause-317-error-code)

Comment: @Bridge Disabling UAC is a **terrible** idea in general, but in this case it won't help, as SQL Server is a service, and services aren't affected (only interactive sessions). Moreover, OP said he trashed his security and gave access to everyone. Clearly, it's not a permissions issue.

Comment: UAC has no power here...

Comment: The SQL runs fine for me, it's not a "bug" as you call it, it's more likely a configuration of your local machine that is the problem.